# File upload procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, web-applications, plsql

I am working on a PL/SQL Oracle web application and I need to make a procedure that processes a file upload form. The file upload form field name is `new_photo`. This is the code I have but I always get an error when I submit. I can't find any examples for this task online or in the oracle documentation.

The error:

```
Error 6550 calling procedure:

ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERT_NEW_PHOTO'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

The last SQL statement executed was:

begin
  insert_new_photo(:B1,:B2,:B3,:B4,:B5,:B6,:B7,:B8);
end;
```

The code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_new_photo (new_photo VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL) IS
    BEGIN

       -- if the user didn't chose a file to upload
       IF new_photo IS NULL OR LENGTH( new_photo ) = 0
       THEN
       print_page_header;
       print_error( 'Please supply a file name.' );
       print_upload_form;
       --print_page_trailer( TRUE );
       return;
   END IF;

END insert_new_photo;
/
```

the form :

```
<form action="insert_new_photo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="new_photo"><br>
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Comment: While @James213 is correct and you seem to have the incorrect number of arguments you also seem to be missing a lot of code. I'm assuming `print_upload_form` and `print_page_header` are procedures? Maybe it's the _insert_ new_photo but it feels like you should have an _insert_ somewhere? What is the definition of "process"?

Comment: print_upload_form and print_page_header are defined just didn't want to make the code very long here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using mod_plsql? If this is the case I don't think you can POST a file directly to a PL/SQL proc: you will have to define a specific table and modify the relevant DAD parameters (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/portal.1111/e12041/concept.htm#i1005866).

HTH.

Alessandro

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i'm wrong but your problem seems to be that you have too many arguments in your call to the procedure

```
insert_new_photo(:B1,:B2,:B3,:B4,:B5,:B6,:B7,:B8);
```

You have 8 arguments here and only one in the procedure itself

```
insert_new_photo (new_photo VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
```

Comment: my procedure works fine when the form type is "text/plain" and not "multipart/form-data" I guess when the form is a "multipart/form-data" form it submits more params or something but I  don't know what parameter is what

Comment: What is the code that is calling this/executing this procedure? IE where is this being called and what is creating :B1, :B2, etc?

Comment: this procedure process a simple form post (I added the form code to the question)